# jQuery File Type Input Plugin needed

Tags: jquery, file-upload, textinput

I am looking to customize the input type  file to a custom browse button. does anyone know of any good plugins i could use of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible due to browser security. You have to use the input element with the type file. I think you can put and image on top of the browser button to customize it as long you make sure that the click event is past to the file input.

Because of browser security you can not access the clients file system with anything other as the file input element. You never get the file structure with a script language such as javascript. Not even when you check the value attribute with for example javascript. The value attribute will only return the filename not the path.

You could try to use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) jquery plugin to customize the button. But that will work with a flash file if I remember correct.

Edit: Yes checked it. It is possible with [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/). There is an option `buttonImg` you can use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads',
    'buttonImg' : '/img/inputbutton.png',
    'auto'      : true
  });
});
```

Comment: i want a plugin to modify the file input element itself

Comment: There is no plugin for modifying the input element itself, because its not possible **due to browser restrictions**.  The best that can be done is to place a styled element on top of a visually hidden file input.

Comment: @simshaun oh ok. is there any tutorial as to how it can be done. am confused a little how i can do it using css

Comment: I suggest checking out this quirksmode article: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: @simshaun Just wanted to paste that :P